# WebStorm refactor JavaScript variable namespace

Tags: javascript, webstorm, automated-refactoring, javascript-namespaces

I have polluted one of my classes with too many functions. Now, I want to clean it up by introducing several namespaces.

Consider following example:

```
const Tool = {};

tool.fct1 = function() { /* ... */ };
tool.fct2 = function() { /* ... */ };
// ...
tool.fctN = function() { /* ... */ };
```

where many external modules make use of these functions

```
import {Tool} from '/path/to/tool.js'

const result = Tool.fctN();
```

Now, introducing namespaces would cause `Tool` to be more structured like this:

```
const Tool = {};

Tool.ns1 = {};
Tool.ns2 = {};

Tool.ns1.fct1 = function() { /* ... */ };
Tool.ns1.fct2 = function() { /* ... */ };
// ...
Tool.ns2.fctN = function() { /* ... */ };
```

So, the depending code has to change to the following structure:

```
import {Tool} from '/path/to/tool.js'

const result = Tool.ns2.fctN();
```

## The problem is

that I tried several refactoring functionality in WebStorm but none allowed me to automatically co-refactor depending code.

**Refactor.Rename**

Obviously the first thing to try. Refactor -> rename `fct1` to `ns1.fct1` 
 Result: WS prevented me from doing that and showed a message `ns1.fct1 is not a valid identifier`. (Works neither when `ns1` being property of `Tool` nor when being not.)

**Refactor.Change-siganture**

Obviously changes only signature and not properties / variables.

**Refactor.Move, Refactor.Copy, Refactor.Safe-Delete**

No ways of changing code in this file as described above.

**Refactor.extract**

Extracting either does not change anything related to the current variable or extracts an inner variable, which does not help to introduce a namespace at all.

**Refactor.Inline**

Trying inline on `Tool.fct1` shows message `cannot inline complex expression evaluation.`

Anybody found a solution to this so that I don't need to rewrite all my code by hand?

Comment: I think you should just try a simple find and replace. Use regex for more control, too.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Will give hat a try  but I am still curious if this is going to work using refactoring.